# Wordpress: Timezone issue of published field (Atom Publishing Protocol Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, atompub

When I post an entry via Atompub API using [WordPress Atom Publishing Protocol Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/atom-publishing-protocol/) (also previous wp-app.php), if the entry includes non-GMT time value as published field like this:

```
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'><title type='text'>test</title><content type='text/html'>test</content>
<published>2013-08-27T00:00:00+09:00</published>
<app:control xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'><app:draft>no</app:draft></app:control><category term='test'/></entry>
```

the timezone (**+09:00**) is not correctly parsed, and same value (GMT time) is stored into `post_date` and `post_date_gmt` field of `wp_posts`.

```
post_date: 2013-08-27 00:00:00
post_date_gmt: 2013-08-27 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `get_publish_time()` function in `wp-content/plugins/atom-publishing-protocol/class-wp-atom-server.php` with following code:

```
/**
 * Retrieve published time to display in XML.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 * @param string $published Time string.
 * @return string
 */
function get_publish_time($published) {
    $pubtime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::RFC3339, $published);

    if (!$pubtime) {
        return array(current_time('mysql'),current_time('mysql',1));
    } else {
        $localtime = $pubtime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $pubtime->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
        $gmttime = $pubtime->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        return array($localtime, $gmttime);
    }
}
```

#### Notice

- Requires PHP >= 5.2
- **If wp-app.php still exists**, the plugin is not used.

#### Reason

It is because `rfc3339_str2time()` function in the original implementation drops timezone information.